# How to remove noDataText completely?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

When I make it empty string, like

```
noDataText=' '
```

...it still show an empty rectangle (class=rt-noData).
'False' doesn't help of course.

What would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-table` allows you to override some internal components so you can replace default `NoDataComponent` with the one that renders `null`. The component can be overridden either globally or per instance.

**Global override:**

```
import { ReactTableDefaults } from 'react-table';

const NullComponent = () => null;
Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults, { NoDataComponent: NullComponent });
```

**Instance override:**

```
const NullComponent = () => null;

<ReactTable
  NoDataComponent={NullComponent}
  ... 
/>
```